# service temporarily unavailable short periods

Tags: server, nginx

I noticed every now and then i would get the "service temporarily unavailable" message on some of my sites running on my server, after refresh it would work again. From what I can see all resources have been allocated correctly so not 100% what is causing this. What logs can i check to pinpoint the problem? I have not tried anything since i don't know what is causing this. I had a look at the php limits and that all seems standard and nothing have been changed.

I am running ubuntu server 14 with nginx.

Comment: I would start by inspecting your nginx error log.

Comment: perfect thank you. it is this one correct `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: had a look now, that log is empty, must i enable debug logging in order to show errors in this log?

Comment: That would be the default error log yes, unless you configured a custom error log for your vhost, errors should appears in there.

Comment: no havent configured anything, i found documentation on how to enable this on nginx website: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/debug/. will keep debugging enabled until problem occurs again.